# pip install error with Raspberry OS 64 bit

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi

Have anyone know how to solve this error?

```
pip install bluepy
```

**error**

```
error-subproccess-exited-with-error
```

Comment: Have you seen [the tutorial?](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy)

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan Yes ,I have try this way

Comment: Okay, i'll update my answer if i find something

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install make`?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! Copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python-pip libglib2.0-dev
```

Then:

```sh
sudo pip install bluepy
```

---

If you get the same error, you may need to install / re-install [cmake](https://cmake.org/install/) and try again:

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Docs / Instructions

> https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy

Comment: You are right. I try   sudo apt-get install python3-pip libglib2.0-dev
then it can work now. Thanks!!

Comment: No worries man 